# Do any DNS registrars support multi factor authentication?

Tags: network, dns, multi-factor

I am looking for a DNS registrar that supports strong multi-factor authentication.

- Does any DNS registrar support multi-factor?
- Is this a legitimate need?

Comment: It absolutely is a legitimate need! Who can compromise your account at your DNS registrar can steal your domain, trivially divert all your resources that are found via DNS (e.g. mail MXes, web sites), and then change the DNSSEC keys and compromise all the DNSSEC-protected things (e.g. SSHFP, DANE), and more. Once DNSSEC becomes well deployed, the weak link in the authentication chain may well be DNS registrars, moreso than the ultimately trusted DNS root key.

Comment: Namecheap.com doesen't offer multi factor authentication, but it give you the option to totally disable the password recovery options of your account

Comment: Legitimate indeed, see this: https://medium.com/p/24eb09e026dd

Comment: https://twofactorauth.org/#domains

Answer (score 9):

I'd say that this could definitely be a legitimate requirement.  Control over DNS records for a domain can give a lot of power to an attacker (adding new hosts in a domain for a phishing attack or even redirecting a comapanies home page), so protecting it from attack is important and as with all publicly accessible high-value services, using 2-factor auth is good thing to consider.

As to providers that support it [DNSimple](http://blog.dnsimple.com/protect-your-dnsimple-account-with-two-factor-authentication-from-authy/) is one that does.